# Custom WP Post-type displays wrong posts in back-end

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have created a custom post type in WordPress, but when I add a new post to this post-type it doesn't show in the list of all posts in the post-type. Instead it displays all posts from the default posts-page.

Function:

```
function create_post_type() {
register_post_type( 'winactie',
    array(
    'labels' => array (
    'name' => __( 'Winactie' ),
    'singular_name' => __( 'Actie' )),
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'winactie'),
)
);
}

add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: "Instead it displays all posts from the default posts-page" this happens in admin page or public page ? Show us the code of your posts page.

Comment: Are you using any caching plugin. If yes then try to clear cache and see if it's work..

Comment: Hi,

Thank you for your reply. I found out another function (that I made to customize the /category archive page) was creating the conflict. When I removed that function the post-type + backend worked as they should.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this link to create new custom post type in admin side it will work perfect result for you .

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-custom-post-types-in-wordpress/

Also please change your post type name to demo post type name.

Answer (score 0):

```
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'winactie',
        array(
        'labels' => array (
        'name' => __( 'Winactie' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Actie' )),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'winactie'),
       )
     );
    }

add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
```

Your code is right and i had tried with your code and there is no error. All post are listing in winactie custom post.

Comment: Hi,

Thank you for your reply. I found out another function (that I made to customize the /category archive page) was creating the conflict. When I removed that function the post-type + backend worked as they should.